# How to order partly inside a data frame according to different columns and values?

Tags: r, dataframe, partial-ordering

I would like to order rows within a data frame according to different columns and I don't know how I could achieve this. Here an example to clarify:

```
x <- data.frame(X=c(10:1), Y=c(6,6,3,6,3,3,9,9,9,2), L=c("A","B","C","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"))
x 
    X Y L 
1  10 6 A
2   9 6 B
3   8 3 C
4   7 6 C
5   6 3 A
6   5 3 B
7   4 9 C
8   3 9 A
9   2 9 B
10  1 2 C
```

to

```
    X Y L
1   3 9 A
2   6 3 A
3  10 6 A
4   9 6 B
5   5 3 B
6   2 9 B
7   1 2 C
8   8 3 C
9   7 6 C
10  4 9 C
```

In this example, the values that are "A" are ordered by increasing "X". The values that have "B" are ordered by decreasing "X" and values with "C" are ordered by increasing "Y".

Can this be done with `order()` or `%>% arrange`?
(data frame is large)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new vector with the conditions which is used by `order`.

```
y <- x$X
i <- x$L == "B"
y[i] <- y[i] * -1
i <- x$L == "C"
y[i] <- x$Y[i]
x[order(x$L, y),]
#    X Y L
#8   3 9 A
#5   6 3 A
#1  10 6 A
#2   9 6 B
#6   5 3 B
#9   2 9 B
#10  1 2 C
#3   8 3 C
#4   7 6 C
#7   4 9 C
```

Comment: That's a great way of doing it; if the dataframe is large, this method will be the fastest

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function which does the job for you. With `order_pattern` you can specify on which columns you want to order and whether it should be increasing or decreasing

```
order_pattern <- list(A = c("X", "inc"), B = c("X", "dec"), C = c("Y", "inc"))
 
order_partly <- function(dat, ord_pat){
  result <- dat[0,]
  for (pattern_col in names(ord_pat)){
    order_col <- ord_pat[[pattern_col]][1]
    decreasing <- if (ord_pat[[pattern_col]][2] == "dec") T else F
    partial_dat <- dat[dat$L == pattern_col,]
    ord <- order(partial_dat[order_col], decreasing = decreasing)
    result <- rbind(result, partial_dat[ord, ])
  }
  result
}

order_partly(x, order_pattern)

    X Y L
8   3 9 A
5   6 3 A
1  10 6 A
2   9 6 B
6   5 3 B
9   2 9 B
10  1 2 C
3   8 3 C
4   7 6 C
7   4 9 C
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a new column and fill it with values corresponding to your ordering scheme, sort by that column, then remove the column (decorate-sort-undecorate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- data.frame(X=c(10:1), Y=c(6,6,3,6,3,3,9,9,9,2), L=c("A","B","C","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"))
x %>%
  group_by(L) %>%
  mutate(shwartz = ifelse(L == "A", X,
                          ifelse(L == "B", 1 / X,
                                 ifelse(L == "C", Y,
                                        "error")))) %>% 
  arrange(L, shwartz) %>% 
  select(-shwartz) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#       X     Y L    
#   <int> <dbl> <chr>
# 1     3     9 A    
# 2     6     3 A    
# 3    10     6 A    
# 4     9     6 B    
# 5     5     3 B    
# 6     2     9 B    
# 7     1     2 C    
# 8     8     3 C    
# 9     7     6 C    
#10     4     9 C
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_split(L) %>%
  map_dfr(~ if(.x$L[1] == "A") {
    .x %>% arrange(.x$X)
  } else if(.x$L[1] == "B") {
    .x %>% arrange(desc(.x$X))
  } else {
    .x %>% arrange(.x$Y)
  })

# A tibble: 10 x 3
       X     Y L    
   <int> <dbl> <chr>
 1     3     9 A    
 2     6     3 A    
 3    10     6 A    
 4     9     6 B    
 5     5     3 B    
 6     2     9 B    
 7     1     2 C    
 8     8     3 C    
 9     7     6 C    
10     4     9 C
```